# Как это называется?

Tags: синтаксис

В нашей грамматике это называется "предложный оборот/фраза"... Как называют выделенное по-русски?

Когда шеф сказал, *безо всякой просьбы с его стороны*, что в его распоряжении будет собственный кабинет, он обрадовался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обособленное обстоятельство, обстоятельственный оборот, предложное сочетание с обстоятельственным значением.